# Upgrading the version of libxml2 that my PHP installation uses

Tags: php

I'm running into some problems upgrading the version of libxml2 that my local PHP install is using. I originally posted about this [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/29706/problem-upgrading-mediawiki-1-5-8-to-mediawiki-1-19-libxml2-inadequate-on-serve/29730#29730), but I've now got some more information so thought it was worthwhile reposting.

I run PHP via XAMPP 1.0.1 installed on OS X 10.7. The version of libxml2 that PHP can see (according to phpinfo()) is 2.7.2. I've used MacPorts to istall libxml2 version 2.7.8, but it seems that PHP is still pointing at version 2.7.2.

How can I go about configuring PHP to use libxml2 version 2.7.8?